# Regex to group 1 with a variety of possibilities

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on parsing an email that's hitting my incoming server with a few conditions that may be variable using python regex. The difficulty here is that any of these conditions must match to group one. The regex I've come up with meets most of the necessary conditions but the final condition eludes me using this regex:

`from [LOC ]*[loc ]*0*(\d* [A-Z]{2} [A-Z]* *[A-Z]*)`

Here are the variations of the string that I'll have to pull my information out of with what I'd be parsing out in code snippet:

"blah blah blah from LOC 0`704 <2Char ABV> <LOCATION NAME>`
some URL after a return line"

"blah blah blah from loc 0`704 <2Char ABV> <LOCATION NAME>`
some URL after a return line"

"blah blah blah from 0`704 <2Char ABV> <LOCATION NAME>`
some URL after a return line"

"blah blah blah from LOC `704 <2Char ABV> <LOCATION NAME>`
some URL after a return line"

"blah blah blah from LOC 000`4 <2Char ABV> <LOCATION NAME WITH A SPACE IN IT>`
some URL after a return line"

"blah blah blah from LOC 000`4 <2Char ABV> <LOCATION NAME WITH A SPACE IN IT>` [0004]
some URL after a return line"

We begin reading the following string at "from" and look for "LOC" or "loc" possibly existing, and continuing on to read any possible leading zeroes in up to four digits and only capturing the digits at the first nonzero on until we reach the end of the location name.

The last condition is that I want to capture all these things but exclude the number in the brackets at the end of the string and any leading spaces prior to it but still capture the  if it exists. I feel like I'm so close here but missing something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a case insensitive match, you might use:

```
\bfrom\s+(?:loc\s+)?0*(\d+\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+[A-Z]+(?:\s+[^][\s]+)+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bfrom\s+` Match from and whitespace chars
- `(?:loc\s+)?` Optionally match loc and whitespace chars
- `0*` Match optional zeroes
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+\s+` Match 1+ digits and whitespace chars
  - `[A-Z]{2}\s+[A-Z]+`Match 2 times A-Z, whitespace chars, 1+ chars A-Z
  - `(?:\s+[^][\s]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching whitespace chars and non whitespace chars except `[` and `]`
- `)` Close group 1

To match spaces wihout newlines, the `\s` can be `[^\S\n]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kOEwRs/1)

To not match newlines and only match till before http or data between square brackets:

```
from[^\S\n]+(?:loc\s+)?0*(\d+[^\S\n]+[A-Z]{2}[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+(?:(?!\s*(?:\[[^][]*]|https?://)).)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YH0DTI/1)

Comment: This looks mostly right, but when applying it to my email it looks like it's still capturing the return and the following URL. I think I left out a circumstance wherein there may not be a [some four-digit number], like this: 
"blah blah blah from LOC 0004 XY ABV a location name
some URL after a return line"

Comment: @AgentTate Can you update this link with the expected matches https://regex101.com/r/kOEwRs/1 or create a new regex101 link with real data examples?

Comment: @AgentTate You could for example matches spaces without newlines `from[^\S\n]+(?:loc\s+)?0*(\d+[^\S\n]+[A-Z]{2}[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[^][\s]+)+)` See https://regex101.com/r/fc3TTB/1 or exclude matching a url or data between brackets `from[^\S\n]+(?:loc\s+)?0*(\d+[^\S\n]+[A-Z]{2}[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+(?:(?!\s*(?:\[[^][]*]|https?://)).)*)` See https://regex101.com/r/YH0DTI/1

Comment: This is what I'm looking at. https://regex101.com/r/dx4elg/1

Comment: @AgentTate Were the example links in the previous comment any helpful?

Comment: Yes, it looks like (?:loc\s+)?0*(\d+[^\S\n]+[A-Z]{2}[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+(?:(?!\s*(?:\[[^][]*]|https?://)).)*) does what I'm looking for. Thank you!